# accept all revisions in a .docx files programmatically in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

My aim is to accept all revisions for a .docx files using Java.
I've already used the apache-poi project to highlight sentences in docx, so I'm not entirely new to that project.

Here is what I've found till now:

- [C# and Visual basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-accept-all-revisions-in-a-word-processing-document) official code for accepting all revisions
- A [Java proposed workaround](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Accepting-all-Changes-Reading-only-accepted-changes-td5718470.html) that uses apache-poi to get the text but does not accept the revisions:

> ```
> public static String getBasicTextFromParagraphWithoutDeletions(XWPFParagraph par) {
>   StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
>   for (IRunElement run : par.getIRuns()) {
>       if (run instanceof XWPFRun) {
>           XWPFRun xRun = (XWPFRun) run;
>           if (xRun.getCTR().getRsidDel() == null) {
>               out.append(xRun.toString());
>           }
>       } else if (run instanceof XWPFSDT) {
>           out.append(((XWPFSDT) run).getContent().getText());
>       } else {
>           out.append(run.toString());
>       }
>   }
>
>   return out.toString();
> }
> ```

- A [perl or python proposal](https://superuser.com/questions/179625/bulk-accept-all-changes-in-microsoft-word-2010-docx-files) to accept all revisions

Does anyone knows if there is a way to accept the revisions in java too?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a utility similar to `com2java` to [build the COM interop for Word as a Java package](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/blog/2004/october/14.html), then leveraging the equivalent of [`ActiveDocument.Revisions.AcceptAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.revisions.acceptall)?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up!